# iOS in-app purchase subscription get free trial period length from SKProduct

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, in-app-subscription, skproduct

I am working on in-app purchases with subscriptions.
In swift, you can get price and price locale from the SKProduct like so:

```
weeklyProduct.price.doubleValue  
weeklyProduct.priceLocale.currencySymbol
```

where weeklyProduct is a SKProduct.

Is it possible to get the free trial length?  For example, I specified a two week free trial for the product.  can I get this from the SKProduct?

Comment: No.  You can get information from the [receipt](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html) that indicates whether the subscription is currently in the free trial period, but not the free trial length

Comment: ah ok, thanks.  got it.

Comment: https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit/issues/85

OR

You can use SwiftyStoreKit

Answer (score 32):

I've solved it using DateComponentsFormatter, that saves you a lot of time localizing in different languages and handling plurals and whatnot.
This might seem like a lot of code, but I hope it will save me time in the future.

```
import Foundation

class PeriodFormatter {
    static var componentFormatter: DateComponentsFormatter {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
        formatter.unitsStyle = .full
        formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .dropAll
        return formatter
    }

    static func format(unit: NSCalendar.Unit, numberOfUnits: Int) -> String? {
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current
        componentFormatter.allowedUnits = [unit]
        switch unit {
        case .day:
            dateComponents.setValue(numberOfUnits, for: .day)
        case .weekOfMonth:
            dateComponents.setValue(numberOfUnits, for: .weekOfMonth)
        case .month:
            dateComponents.setValue(numberOfUnits, for: .month)
        case .year:
            dateComponents.setValue(numberOfUnits, for: .year)
        default:
            return nil
        }

        return componentFormatter.string(from: dateComponents)
    }
}
```

It requires to convert the SKProduct period unit into a NSCalendarUnit

```
import StoreKit

@available(iOS 11.2, *)
extension SKProduct.PeriodUnit {
    func toCalendarUnit() -> NSCalendar.Unit {
        switch self {
        case .day:
            return .day
        case .month:
            return .month
        case .week:
            return .weekOfMonth
        case .year:
            return .year
        @unknown default:
            debugPrint("Unknown period unit")
        }
        return .day
    }
}
```

And you can call it from a SubscriptionPeriod like this:

```
import StoreKit

@available(iOS 11.2, *)
extension SKProductSubscriptionPeriod {
    func localizedPeriod() -> String? {
        return PeriodFormatter.format(unit: unit.toCalendarUnit(), numberOfUnits: numberOfUnits)
    }
}
```

Which you can in turn call from a SKProductDiscount like so. Please note I didn't implement the other PaymentModes for now.

```
import StoreKit

@available(iOS 11.2, *)
extension SKProductDiscount {
    func localizedDiscount() -> String? {
        switch paymentMode {
        case PaymentMode.freeTrial:
            return "Free trial for \(subscriptionPeriod.localizedPeriod() ?? "a period")"
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The most elegant solution as it properly takes into account localization.

Comment: Nice, but this will give a string in the language of the device. If the app is not localized in that language you will end up with UI text in two languages. To solve this replace `dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current` with

 let interfaceLanguage = Bundle.preferredLocalizations(from:Bundle.main.localizations).first;
 let locale = Locale(identifier: interfaceLanguage ?? "en");
 dateComponents.calendar = locale.calendar;

Answer (score 20):

You can get it, but as mentioned above it works only starting from iOS 11.2, for other versions you'll have to get it from your server via API.

Here is an example code that I've used:

```
if #available(iOS 11.2, *) {
  if let period = prod.introductoryPrice?.subscriptionPeriod {
     print("Start your \(period.numberOfUnits) \(unitName(unitRawValue: period.unit.rawValue)) free trial")
  }
} else {
  // Fallback on earlier versions
  // Get it from your server via API
}

func unitName(unitRawValue:UInt) -> String {
    switch unitRawValue {
    case 0: return "days"
    case 1: return "weeks"
    case 2: return "months"
    case 3: return "years"
    default: return ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Using [Eslam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50604569/4896756) as inspiration I created an extension to SKProduct.PeriodUnit

```
extension SKProduct.PeriodUnit {
    func description(capitalizeFirstLetter: Bool = false, numberOfUnits: Int? = nil) -> String {
        let period:String = {
            switch self {
            case .day: return "day"
            case .week: return "week"
            case .month: return "month"
            case .year: return "year"
            }
        }()

        var numUnits = ""
        var plural = ""
        if let numberOfUnits = numberOfUnits {
            numUnits = "\(numberOfUnits) " // Add space for formatting
            plural = numberOfUnits > 1 ? "s" : ""
        }
        return "\(numUnits)\(capitalizeFirstLetter ? period.capitalized : period)\(plural)"
    }
}
```

To use:

```
if #available(iOS 11.2, *),
    let period = prod?.introductoryPrice?.subscriptionPeriod
{
    let desc = period.unit.description(capitalizeFirstLetter: true, numberOfUnits: period.numberOfUnits)
} else {
    // Fallback
}
```

This will create a nicely formatted string (e.g. 1 day, 1 Week, 2 months, 2 Years)

Comment: Great answer. If you want to localise, use stringdicts instead of `plural` variable : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/StringsdictFileFormat/StringsdictFileFormat.html

Comment: Man, it works for English only. Each language may have its own endings. For example in Russian you use different endings for 1, 2-4 and 5+ unit count and 5+ "years" is replaced with another word at all.

Answer (score 2):

Nice one @scott Wood. I would make it a property of `SKProduct.PeriodUnit` instead of a function. That would keep the behaviour more consistent with enums:

```
@available(iOS 11.2, *)
extension SKProduct.PeriodUnit {

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .day: return "day"
        case .week: return "week"
        case .month: return "month"
        case .year: return "year"
        // support for future values
        default:
            return "N/A"
        }
    }

    func pluralisedDescription(length: Int) -> String {
        let lengthAndDescription = length.description + " " + self.description
        let plural = length > 1 ?  lengthAndDescription + "s" : lengthAndDescription
        return plural
    }
}
```

And then a function to return the plural, based on the `description` property.

And yes, as someone else pointed out, you should localise the plurals if your app is available in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit), `localizedSubscriptionPeriod` is the easiest way

```swift
import SwiftyStoreKit

product.introductoryPrice?.localizedSubscriptionPeriod // "1 week"
```

This is the implementation:
https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit/blob/master/Sources/SwiftyStoreKit/SKProductDiscount+LocalizedPrice.swift

Answer (score 0):

Trial length is not included in the SKProduct information and will have to be hardcoded into the app or stored on your server. The only available option for deriving this type of information (currently) is from the receipt itself.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from iOS 11.2 you can get info about trials using [`introductoryPrice`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproduct/2936878-introductoryprice?changes=latest_minor) property of `SKProduct`.

It contains instance of [`SKProductDiscount`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproductdiscount?changes=latest_minor) class, which describes all discount periods including free trials.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

Using [Eslam's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50604569/2053537) and [Scott's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51657790/2053537) answers as inspiration:

```
import StoreKit

extension SKProduct {
    func priceString() -> String {
        let period:String = {
            switch self.subscriptionPeriod?.unit {
            case .day: return "day"
            case .week: return "week"
            case .month: return "month"
            case .year: return "year"
            case .none: return ""
            case .some(_): return ""
            }
        }()

        let price = self.localizedPrice!
        let numUnits = self.subscriptionPeriod?.numberOfUnits ?? 0
        let plural = numUnits > 1 ? "s" : ""
        return String(format: "%@ for %d %@%@", arguments: [price, numUnits, period, plural])
    }
}
```

To use:

```
let price = product.priceString()
print(price)
```

Result:

```
THB 89.00 for 7 days
THB 149.00 for 1 month
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (NSString*)localizedTitleForSKPeriod:(SKProductSubscriptionPeriod*)period{
    NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
    NSDateComponentsFormatter *fmt = [NSDateComponentsFormatter new];
    switch (period.unit) {
        case SKProductPeriodUnitDay:{
            fmt.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitDay;
            comps.day = period.numberOfUnits;
        }break;
        case SKProductPeriodUnitWeek:{
            fmt.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth;
            comps.weekOfMonth = period.numberOfUnits;
        }break;
        case SKProductPeriodUnitMonth:{
            fmt.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitMonth;
            comps.month = period.numberOfUnits;
        }break;
        case SKProductPeriodUnitYear: {
            fmt.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitYear;
            comps.year = period.numberOfUnits;
        }break;
    }
    // 1 Day, 1 Week, 2 Weeks, 1 Month, 2 Months, 3 Months, 6 Months, 1 Year
    fmt.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleFull;
    // One Day, One Week, Two Weeks, etc
    //fmt.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleSpellOut;
    NSString *s = [[fmt stringFromDateComponents:comps] capitalizedString];
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OBJECTIVE C

```
#import "SKProduct+SKProduct.h"

-(NSString*_Nullable)localizedTrialDuraion{

if (@available(iOS 11.2, *)) {
    
    NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setUnitsStyle:NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleFull]; //e.g 1 month
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehaviorDropAll;
    NSDateComponents * dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
    [dateComponents setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];
    
    switch (self.introductoryPrice.subscriptionPeriod.unit) {
        case SKProductPeriodUnitDay:{
            formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitDay;
            [dateComponents setDay:self.introductoryPrice.subscriptionPeriod.numberOfUnits];
            break;
        }
        case SKProductPeriodUnitWeek:{
            formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth;
            [dateComponents setWeekOfMonth:self.introductoryPrice.subscriptionPeriod.numberOfUnits];
            break;
        }
        case SKProductPeriodUnitMonth:{
            formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitMonth;
            [dateComponents setMonth:self.introductoryPrice.subscriptionPeriod.numberOfUnits];
            break;
        }
        case SKProductPeriodUnitYear:{
            formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitYear;
            [dateComponents setYear:self.introductoryPrice.subscriptionPeriod.numberOfUnits];
            break;
        }
        default:{
            return nil;
            break;
        }
            break;
    }
    [dateComponents setValue:self.introductoryPrice.subscriptionPeriod.numberOfUnits forComponent:formatter.allowedUnits];
    return [formatter stringFromDateComponents:dateComponents];
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}

return nil;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Here is more compact and short in use version for swift 5, extending SKProductSubscriptionPeriod

Usage:

```
print("\(period.localizedDescription) free trial")

//Printed example "1 week free trial"
```

Implementation:

```
extension SKProductSubscriptionPeriod {
    public var localizedDescription: String {
        let period:String = {
            switch self.unit {
            case .day: return "day"
            case .week: return "week"
            case .month: return "month"
            case .year: return "year"
            @unknown default:
                return "unknown period"
            }
        }()
    
        let plural = numberOfUnits > 1 ? "s" : ""
        return "\(numberOfUnits) \(period)\(plural)"
    }
}
```